# printing the ascii codes for small alphabets

Tags: java, ascii

How can i print the ascii codes of both the capital and small alphabets . ? For example on pressing `q` from keyboard,`evt.getKeyCode()` gives me 81 which is the ASCII code for capital Q. How can i print the ascii code for small alphabets ?

Comment: whether the caps lock is on or off , result is the same. why so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyEvent.getKeyCode()` only for the basic letters and digits returns the ASCII code.
You get 65 for `A` with ASCII code 65 and `a` with ASCII code 65+32. With `!evt.isShiftDown()` you can then say it was an `a`.

The key codes are invented by Java, so called virtual keys. The constant VK_A is haphazardly chosen to be the ASCII code of A/a.

Comment: what does is `isShiftDown` actually do ? I read the doc `returns whether shift modifier is down or not` but didn't understand what it means

Comment: To press 'a' you press the A-key (VK_A). To press 'A' you press both VK_SHIFT and VK_A. VK_A goes to the key code; VK_SHIFT goes to a bit mask in the so called "modifiers" field. So it simply means "shift down".

Comment: yes that is a good way to check. To me what a bit mask is,what is a modifier is not clear. Are there some good sources from where i can read them.Please tell if you know any

Comment: you could press Alt, Shift, Ctrl in any combination. Assume VK_ALT = 1, VK_SHIFT = 2, and VK_CTRL = 4, then modifiers = 5 would mean Alt and Ctrl were pressed. This is bit arithmetic with & and |. Good reading I do not know ad hoc.

Answer (score 1):

As in ASCII A = 65 and a = 97, we see there is an offset of 97-65 = 32 between capital and lower case.

If you get Q = 81 you can add 32 to get 113 = q.

```
char c = (char)(evt.getKeyCode() + 32);
```

Comment: whether the caps lock is on or off , result is the same. why so ?

Comment: I believe KeyEvent class does not care about the case of the key because q or Q is the same key on a keyboard. If you want to distinguish q and Q key you have to check if Shift is pressed or not. I think...